# How to configure Cloud Endpoints to the existing spring Boot application (Running on App Engine)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

Spring Boot App is running on App engine(suppose https://zzzzzz.appspot.com).
 So, Want to use cloud endpoints at first place to trigger the request to spring boot app .

Comment: have you tried going through the samples from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java) to try and add the Endpoints API to your already running App Engine instance?

Comment: Thanks @bhito , But unfortunately Endpoints Frameworks doesn't support the App Engine flexible environment.

The documentation link that you have provided is about Endpoints Frameworks for App engine standard, But that can be done via manually ESP running on a cloud run if we want to use App Engine Standard.

But the question here for App Engine Flex + Spring boot + Endpoints ?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't know which environment you were using for your GAE instance. As you are using flex environment, you can refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine#java) on how to use Endpoints with GAE flex. You will have to deploy the endpoints configuration file specifying your GAE instance in the host field.

Comment: Hey @bhito - Thanks for you link, I was following the same earlier, But it was in java language and way of deploying was different when you use spring boot language. So, I mixed both of the link -  [link](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine#java)(java) + [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/helloworld-springboot) (Spring Boot) , then only i can see the graphs updated at endpoints.

Thanks a lot for your Help :)

Comment: The point is that if you already have your GAE instance with spring boot running, there shouldn't be any issue deploying endpoints. Is a different service which will be deployed as a container linked to your GAE running instance. You will deploy your GAE instance using `mvn appengine:deploy` and the endpoints config using `gcloud endpoints services deploy openapi-appengine.yaml`.
Btw, I have seen [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-cloud-endpoints/Vy8egehPZV0/lQigdVhLAgAJ) that you managed to make it work. Is it currently working for you?

Comment: Yes @bhito :  It is working for me. The problem was with the graphs and monitoring logs for Spring Boot app in Endpoint screen on GCP earlier, not with the deploying the endpoints.

Comment: Great, glad to hear that you managed to make it work. Perhaps you could post an answer with the solution you come up with so other members from the community can see it and use it as well.

Comment: Yes Sure @bhito